Why is Inversion Temperature not equal to Boyle's temperature?(Theoretically)
Mathematically, it is proven that the inversion temperature is twice that of Boyle's temperature.
But if a gas is not showing the Joule-Thompson effect, it is behaving ideally and it has no interaction between molecules to overcome. So why, at Boyle's temperature when it is behaving ideally, can it still show the Joule-Thompson effect?

Real gases obtain various aspects of the ideal gas at different conditions, not all aspects at once. Boyle condition p =(approx) RT/Vm does not mean (dT/dp)_H = 0 (J-T) condition.

Mathematically, I understand but again if at Boyle's temperature the gas has only some of the aspects of an ideal gas, and it also has some aspects of it at inversion temperature, There would be absolutely no difference between the two

At one pV=nRT and (dT/dp)_H <>0, as energy consumed by breaking attraction forces is different than energy release from elastic repulsion.  At the other pV<>nRT and (dT/dp)_H = 0 // By other words, one case is about ratio of integral values, the other case is about the ration of differential values.

Thanks, I am starting to understand this
